# Images field returning as undefined in Facebook Graph Api

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to return the field images through the callback function and passing it into the element wall-post but it comes up undefined. I am wondering if there's a function that involves a url tag that can define the field?

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId            : '*********',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v2.12'


    });
        FB.api('https://graph.facebook.com/page_name/posts/?access_token=****************', {fields: 'message,link,created_time,name,story, images'}, function(response) 
            {
                for (var l = response.data.length, i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    var obj = response.data[i];



                        var node = document.createElement("wall-post");  
                        //var node2 = document.createElement("wall-post-header");  
                            var textNode = document.createTextNode(obj.images);
                            //var timeNode = document.createTextNode(obj.created_time);
                                node.appendChild(textNode);
                                //node2.appendChild(timeNode);
                                node.style=' display: inline-block;margin: 15px;margin-top: 30px; border-radius: px;overflow-y: hidden;box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);float:left;';
                                //node2.style='height: 50px;overflow: hidden;background-color:#272727;color: white;line-height: 31px;padding: 9px;float: right;text-align: right;display: inline-block;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;font-size: 12px; line-height: 31px;padding: 9px;float: left;text-align: left;display: inline-block;-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;-moz-box-sizing: border-box;box-sizing: border-box;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;width: 70%';
                            document.body.appendChild(node);
                            //document.body.appendChild(node2);

                        }
                    })
                };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')
);
```

Comment: Since you just exposed your app access token here, the very first thing you need to go do now, is go reset your app secret via the app dashboard. Neither app nor page access tokens should be exposed in client-side code, so unless you are the only one who will ever access this, you need to either make the user log in to your app, so that you can use their user access token for this - or you have to do it on the server-side to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe Done! Would you have a solution to the image field returning as undefined?

Comment: You should always try such requests in Graph API Explorer first - its debug message would have told you that there is not such field  `image` on Post object nodes.

Comment: @CBroe I changed the request to page_name/photos/uploaded and it's still returning as undefined. Is there a request that returns the image in jpg notation?

Comment: Now are you looking for posts, or uploaded photos? Both are completely different things.

Comment: @CBroe Posts preferably as it's for a public page. I was just using the previous request as a test.

Comment: Then check the post fields picture, full_picture and attachments, and see if what you get in there is what you want.

Comment: @CBroe Yes the picture field returns the links of the images I want to display. How do I go about displaying the pictures the links are associated with?

Comment: You put the URL into the `src` attribute of an `img` element …?

Comment: @CBroe Oh sorry wasn't thinking, I would've thought it was more difficult then that! Thanks for your help!